# DropzoneJS Event Listener won't loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, dropzone.js

I have followed the usage examples from the DropzoneJS documentation and some other from stackoverflow. However, I still can't make it work. Here is my Dropzone Code.

```
   <p class="h6 my-0 mb-10">PEMERIKSAAN</p>
     <form action="{{url('radiologi/upload/gambar')}}" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="saltPict" value="{{$key}}">
       <input type="hidden" name="target" value="{{$transaksi->slug}}">
         {{csrf_field()}}
     </form>
```

And here, the javascript code that I've added to catch the event which isn't worked.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        init: function() {
            this.on("complete", function (file) {
                if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                    $("#submit-all").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
            this.on("processing", function (file) {
                console.log("check");
                $("#submit-all").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            });
        }
    };
    // $("#my-dropzone").dropzone();
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone.init();
</script>
```

I've try to place the javascript code either inside the document ready function or not. Still, it doesn't work. The only error output is this

[image: Error output]

My only purpose is to catch the event when DropzoneJS has done uploading all of my files.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, It's worked like magic. I just try one more example from the Dropzone documentation. Surprisingly, the code are simpler.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(function() {
        // Now that the DOM is fully loaded, create the dropzone, and setup the
        // event listeners
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
        myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
            console.log("halo");
            /* Maybe display some more file information on your page */
        });
    })
```

And **don't place this on $(document).ready function** so it will be called before the Dropzone itself are attached. Thanks for anyone who has tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should't call `myDropzone.init` by your self, dropzone will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone triggers events when processing files, to which you can register easily, by calling `.on(eventName, callbackFunction)` on your instance.

Since listening to events can only be done on instances of Dropzone, the best place to setup your event listeners, is in the init function:

```
// The recommended way from within the init configuration:
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
init: function() {
this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
     }
   };
```

Comment: thats what I've done now, but it shows an error. Look at my post.